# Copy the content of one cell, and insert within 2 characters, in the middle of a text content from another cell (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to batch copy the content of the cells in column A, and insert it within the "><" of the text in the column B. The result should look like the output in column C. Here is an example:

I would appreciate any response!

```
Column A
This is 
a test 
I hope it works
Alarm Triggered 

Column B
<string name="app_name"></string>
<string name="alarme_service_ativado"></string>
<string name="alarme_service_desativado"></string>
<string name="alarme_service_disparado"></string>

Column C
<string name="app_name">This is </string>
<string name="alarme_service_ativado">a test </string>
<string name="alarme_service_desativado">I hope it works</string>
<string name="alarme_service_disparado">Alarm Triggered</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula in Column C should be as follows then:

```
=MID(B1,1,SEARCH("><",B1,1))&A1&MID(B1,SEARCH("><",B1,1)+1,LEN(B1)-SEARCH("><",B1,1))
```

**RESULT:**

[image]